# Java program throws error on selenium driver unpacked from .jar

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, jar, runtime-error

I have a problem with implementing automatic chromedriver for Selenium *unpacking* from .jar file.

Having

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    File f = new File("Driver");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
    File chromeDriver = new File("Driver" + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe");
    if (!chromeDriver.exists()) {
        try {
            chromeDriver.createNewFile();
            org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(resource, chromeDriver);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return chromeDriver.getAbsolutePath();
```

in one class, that returns the *path* to the executable driver, which is used in

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", the_path);
```

Printing out *path* gives me obviously proper path to the driver file, and the file is being created under given directory right.
Yet, while running .jar the following problem occures

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

but only while triggering the class that's using the driver.

Is there anything to be changed in the code itself or am I missing some crucial things in compilepath or something similiar?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The exception states that org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be found. This has nothing to do with chromedriver.

Comment: Everything goes fine while being run from IntelliJ; I have added standalone server etc. yet still I receive something like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Set the classpath](https://test-able.blogspot.com/2014/11/run-web-driver-scripts-from-command-prompt.html).

Comment: How to do that in IntelliJ?

Comment: You said that it ran fine in IntelliJ. The link I gave you shows how to run the same test on the command line outside of an IDE.  Ignore the Eclipse stuff; IntelliJ has equivalent features. You can figure it out. :-)

Comment: It's more like a program with a GUI etc. that I use as in need of logging into pages that HTMLUnit can't handle. Hope it won't change a thing... (?)

Comment: The problem is that your selenium jar is not in your classpath. That is what you have to fix. See for example this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project).

Comment: @Canert - Can you please tell us how you are building your code as a jar and how you are running it from the command prompt ? If you are basically exporting your code from the IDE as a jar, then the jars setup in your build path are not bundled in your jar. In those cases, you would need to specify the selenium standalone jar as part of your class path and then run your code. So it would be better if you can help answer these questions so that we can help you out.

Comment: I'm simply building an artifact in IntelliJ, having everything needed added to "dependecies" and "libraries" tabs in project structure menu. And then just run the resulting .jar via command prompt. And as a person focusing on a code, I have no idea how to add something to or change classpath.

Comment: Forgot earlier - the solution was simply to add libs folder to the project build ("include in project build").